# application server restart on OOM exception

Tags: java, out-of-memory, websphere-6.1, heap-dump

Can we automatically restart a websphere application server v6.1 on OOM exception after heap dump is created?we have an enterprise application hosted on websphere application server,recently we are facing OOM exceptions,and from time to time the app server gets automatically restarted after the heap dump is generated.But recently the app server restart is not happening automatically but has to be done manually.Can you please let me know what may be the issue

Comment: WAS usually tries to restart the server instance after it has reached an OutOfMemoryError, but you should really try to find the cause of the error. Why are you running out of memory in your application? How long does it take before you reach the OutOfMemoryError after a fresh restart?

Comment: The OOM exceprion is data related.A definite kind of data creates a huge amount of data which the heap cannot handle.Increasing the heap size is not an option,we are working on the data related issue.But it still does not answer my question.If restarting the application server is a WAS property then can you provide me where to find the setting in WAS admin console.Secondly if its a WAS property why is it not working now

Comment: I know my comment about trying to find the cause of the error does not answer your actual question. Either way. I do not know why the behaviour on your server has changed but I have never found that the automatic restart feature is 100% reliable in WAS 6.1, at least not with the applications I have run across. As far as I am aware, this is not any setting you can choose to switch on/off.

Answer (score 0):

There is no in built/parameter based option in WAS 6.1 answering your question. It comes in v.7.0.

Better way I/Many follow is write a basic java program to monitor the sysout.log/ syserr.log for the particular String "OutOfMemory" or "in total in the server that may be hung". If the log has any of those string, then (i) stop the server, (ii) rotate the logs (iii)start the server.

Schedule this java program for every 2 or 5 mins.

I wont recommend this method, This is not a good practice as well. I would recommend WASADM should inform the data related team to fix the issue and providing the logs, threads, hprofs, etc..

But most of the time, it is difficult and time consuming for data/application team to fix it immediately. So WAS administrator has to follow these kind of methods.